# Why does minimizing and restoring a Window has an effect on already drawn graphics in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7

I have a very rudimentary test application only consisting of a `Window` and a `CustomControl`. The window contains the custom control and has the following additional attributes:

```
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
UseLayoutRounding="True"
RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
```

The custom control has these 5 lines added to the code-behind file:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    var pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
    drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, 0), new Point(ActualWidth, ActualHeight)); 
}
```

Everything works great. A black 1px line is draw diagonally from the upper left to the bottom right corner. Perfect. Admittedly pixelated, but exactly what I need. However, when I minimize the window and restore it again the line gets "blurred". This happens without the `OnRender` method getting called again after the window has been restored. So why do drawn graphics fundamentally change after the window was minimized (loosing focus doesn't seem to be the problem)? Why is everything back to normal after the window is simply resized and how can I take care of this unwanted behavior? Forcing a complete resize/invalidate each time the `WindowState` changes seems a little excessive, no?

**Update 1:**

As @Backlash suggested I put the custom control inside a canvas

```
<Canvas Name="CanvasControl" SizeChanged="FrameworkElement_OnSizeChanged">
  <wpfTest:CustomControl x:Name="ChildControl" />
</Canvas>
```

and handled the `SizeChanged` event like this

```
private void FrameworkElement_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ChildControl.Width = CanvasControl.ActualWidth;
    ChildControl.Height = CanvasControl.ActualHeight;
}
```

since elements inside a canvas are not automatically layouted. However, the results did not change.

**Update 2:**

One idea that crossed my mind was listening to changes to the window state and force a resize - and therefore a complete redraw - of the window and all its controls by slightly changes the `Width` or `Height` property of the window:

```
protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
{
        if (WindowState != WindowState.Minimized)
        {               
            Width += 1;
        }
}
```

This works in some circumstances (although not when the `Window` is maximized for example), but generally speaking this is a blatantly bad approach for a number of reasons. I tried to understand what causes a (correct) redraw when the size is changed and it might have something to do with `CoreFlags.AreTransformsClean`, but since everything is either declared internal or privat I gave up on using those flags and any of the associated methods.

**Update 3:**

Given that WPF seems to be helplessly overburdened with drawing straight lines directly on the screen, I tried drawing into a in-memory bitmap first and than paint the bitmap onto the screen. And it works. Here is the method:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    var line = new Line();
    RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(line, EdgeMode.Aliased);

    line.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
    line.StrokeThickness = 1;
    line.X1 = 0;
    line.X2 = ActualWidth;
    line.Y1 = 0;
    line.Y2 = ActualHeight;
    line.Arrange(new Rect(new Size((int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight)));
    rtb.Render(line);

    drawingContext.DrawImage(rtb, new Rect(0, 0, (int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight));
}
```

The "solution" is hacky to say the least. It's really bad, but compared to the rest I have seen so far from WPF this might be a legit approach. However, will leave the thread open for some further answers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you place the custom control inside a Canvas container instead of directly on the window?

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately the results did not change. The line was still blurry after restoring the window from the minimized state.

Comment: Perhaps consider the Path class?

Comment: Have you tried setting IsLayoutRounding on the whole window? Btw. you are never drawing "directly" to the screen, to be precise even in your OnRender you are not drawing anything. WPF tracks your changes as a list of macros or drawing jobs. Thats why WPF doesn't need to recall your drawing code, if it has to redraw it, for example after another window overlaps your window. It only redraws if the visual was invalidated(because of a resize).

Comment: I'd quite like to have a tinker around with this one but, I can't reproduce the blurred line (just a nasty pixelated one) after minimising and restoring. Do you still have the original xaml?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are using

```
SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
```

Pixel snapping is not always exactly accurate according to the [Microsoft msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Unfortunately, simply adjusting the container object's size does not guarantee device pixel alignment. The entire layout of an application can have an affect on the alignment of the image. The display dots per inch (dpi) also affects image alignment. In the example above, the image alignment will only work if the display is set to 96 dots per inch (dpi). At any other setting, the layout needs to be adjusted to accommodate the display settings. High frequency images should be avoided whenever possible in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications.

So try to change that flag to false and see what it does